# Eclipse remote debugging, breakpoints - .java VS .class confusion

Tags: java, eclipse, breakpoints, remote-debugging

I'm remotely debugging a Java application in Eclipse. (Bunch of Alfresco projects with attached sources in ZIP-files.)

Breakpoints do work, but:

1) Whenever I set a breakpoint in *.class file Eclipse opens *.java file when the breakpoint is reached.

2) When I set the breakpoint from within the *.java file a ***new*** breakpoint is created (apparently independent on the one set in *.class), and in the breakpoints list it does not offer 'Go to file' option.

3) The bullet indicating a breakpoint is never displayed in the *.java file; Regardless of whether the breakpoint has been created from within *.class or *.java file.

(If it wasn't for 2 and 3 I would happily stick with *.java files, of course.)

Am I doing something wrong? ...or is this usual behaviour and there's nothing I can do about it?

Comment: Do you have the source file only in one project or more? Tell me when you press Ctrl+Shift+T to open a Java class, Foo it shows you only one Foo or more?

Comment: Only one. (And Ctrl+Shift+R does not show the *.java file either.)

Answer (score 2):

Check your "Order and Export" in the "Java Build Path" preference of your project.
(or in the 'Classpath' tab' of your Run Configuration Launcher)

For a local project, if the output directory ('`build`' or '`bin`' or '`cls`' or ...) appears *before* the '`src`' of what you are debugging, you will experience that kind of "breakpoint" mix-up.

For a remote project, if the jar has the sources attached to them, it should work.

Comment: The 'build' folder is not listed in the Order and Export tab at all. I'm thinking the keyword here is 'remote' (debugging), i.e. no code of my own is involved, yet.

Comment: For example LoginBean.class is linked from alfresco-web-client-3.3g.jar in Referenced Libraries, this JAR has attached source in ZIP. Even when I move this JAR to the very first place in the Order and Export it does not make a difference.

Comment: @Jaroslav: not sure, but can you try adding the sources directly as a "library", and put that before the `alfresco-web-client-3.3g.jar` (which would keep the same zip as attached sources)

Comment: /src added to 'Libraries', moved to the first place in 'Order and Export', Eclipse still opens LoginBean.java :(

Comment: @Jaroslav: "still opens LoginBean.java": oops, that was my intention actually: does a breakpoint works in that Java file?

Comment: kinda yes, except that 1) in the file the breakpoint bullet (on the left) is not displayed, 2) double-click on the breakpoint in the breakpoints list does nothing and 3) i can't quick-find the file via Ctrl+Shift+T nor +R

Comment: @Jaroslav: darn... I hoped it would have improved the situation at least a little. Still looking.